# Plot indicating Tower Property of conditional expectation

Tags: predictive-models, goodness-of-fit, conditional-expectation, sigma-algebra

During my work I encountered a plot, in which we have two curves indicating:

1. Mean value of observations of dependent variable $Y$ (in my case it was annual frequency of claims), calculated for diffent values of some other variable, let's say $Z$;
2. Mean predicted value $\hat{Y}$, which is an evaluation in data point of estimate of conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathbf{X})$ for some vector of variable $\mathbf{X}$, calculated for different values of $Z$.

Plot described above serves for checking *goodness-of-fit*: if two curves don't coincide on some part of a range of variable $Z$, then we should consider adding this variable to our vector $\mathbf{X}$ in some form, since our statistical model does not capture variability of $Y$ across range of $Z$.

To gain more insight into this tool, I translated its content into probabilistic language:

- (1) would be a nonparametric estimate of conditional mean $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z=\cdot)$;
- (2) would be an estimate of $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathbf{X})|Z=\cdot)$.

After this step I realized, that desirable "closeness" of two aforementioned quantities looks the same as *Tower Property* for conditional expectations, which, in a language of sub-sigma-algebras $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{H}$, states that:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{H})|\mathcal{G})=\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})\quad a.s.\quad (*)
$$

This observation provides a reformulation of a meaning of plot: "closeness" of $\mathbb{E}(Y|Z=\cdot)$ and $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathbf{X})|Z=\cdot)$ says that $Z$ provides no additional information- its predictive power is already contained in $\mathbf{X}$.

But here I started to wonder, if I am fully right: truth of condition $\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{H}$ is sufficient, but maybe not necessary for $(*)$ to hold.

Here arise my questions:

1. Is it true that $(*)\Rightarrow\mathcal{G}\subseteq\mathcal{H}$? If no, what is an example of situation, where $(*)$ hold, but $\mathcal{G}$ is not a subset of $\mathcal{H}$?
2. Do you have an experience with plots like one described above? Do you agree with my interpretation? Any additions and corrections are welcome.

**Edit**
(1) My progress after comments of @whuber: assuming that $(*)$ is true, by linearity of conditional expectation we have:
$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{H})-Y|\mathcal{G})=0\quad a.s.
$$
By defining equations of conditional expectation, for all $G\in\mathcal{G}$:
$$
\mathbb{E}([\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{H})-Y]\mathbf{1}_G)=\mathbb{E}(0\mathbf{1}_G)=0\\\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{H})\mathbf{1}_G)=\mathbb{E}(Y\mathbf{1}_G)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{G})\mathbf{1}_G).
$$
Here I am struggling again since I cannot establish from equation above any relation between $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: I can't even make sense of $(*)$ unless $\mathcal G\subseteq\mathcal H.$  What definition of conditional expectation are you using?

Comment: @whuber I am using classical one: for integrable $Y$ it is a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable, which has equal integrals with $Y$, on $G\in\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Then why is there any question here?  The implication is immediate.

Comment: @whuber I added "edit" section to my question.

Comment: The very notation implies $E(Y\mid\mathcal H)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, whence $\mathcal G$ is a subalgebra of $\mathcal H.$

Comment: I really cannot understand why notation implies that $E(Y\mid\mathcal H)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable; even given this step, I don't see how this implies $\mathcal G\subseteq\mathcal H$. Could you please elaborate, to which properties of conditional expectation / integrals / measureability are you referring to in these two steps?

Comment: The *definition* of conditional expectation states that it's a random variable measurable with respect to the conditioning subalgebra.  The right hand side of the tower property equation conditions on $\mathfrak G,$ which is obviously $\mathfrak G$ measurable, whence the left side must be, too.

Comment: The left hand side $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{H})|\mathfrak G )$ also conditions on $\mathfrak G$, so how does this imply that inner conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{H})$ is $\mathfrak G$-measurable?

Comment: You are correct -- I apologize for my mistake.  The inner expectation does not have to be $\mathfrak G$ measurable.  The point I was trying to make is that simply from the fact that you are conditioning, the algebra on which you are conditioning *must* be a subalgebra.